# When does the React component constructor run in relation to life cycle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor

When does the React constructor run relative to component lifecycle?

The newest diagram I found for component lifecycle was here:

[here](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2400/1*sn-ftowp0_VVRbeUAFECMA.png)

and it is from 2017 and does not include the constructor for some reason.

When does the constructor() run and is there a newer diagram available in mid 2019?

Comment: I created a lifecycle visualizer that might be helpful to answer questions like these: https://github.com/Oblosys/react-lifecycle-visualizer#react-lifecycle-visualizer--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will occur in the mount phase as seen in these two diagrams by [Mosh](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-lifecycle-methods/)

and by [Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/reactjs-component-lifecycle-methods-a-deep-dive-38275d9d13c0):

Answer (score 1):

The order the React components and constructor works are;

1. The object memory is allocated
2. The field variables with initial values are initialized
3. Constructor is called
4. React component code is called.